# How should a long-lived connection behave when there is a DNS change?

Tags: domain-name-system, tcp

Scenario:

1. `Connector.com` connects to `server.net`, which resolves to `20.30.40.50`
2. `Connector.com` and `20.30.40.50` keep the connection open
3. DNS is updated so that `server.net` now resolves to `7.8.9.10`

Should `Connector.com` recognize that `server.net` now resolves to something different and open a new connection?  How should this be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should Connector.com recognize that server.net now resolves to something different and open a new connection?

Usually not. DNS is only used to find the address for a specific name but the association (TCP connection) is between two IP addresses and not between two hostnames.

It still might be that your application requires a different behavior. But this would be application logic then and will vary depending on the requirements of the specific application.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Should Connector.com recognize that server.net now resolves to something different and open a new connection?

A: No.

If you wanted Connector.com to establish a new connection you'd have to terminate the existing connection, flush its DNS cache, flush the DNS cache of its upstream DNS servers and make a new connection.